# How can be configured kafka-connect-file-pulse for continuous reading of a text file?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have FilePulse correctly configured, so that when I create a file inside the reading folder, it reads it and ingests it in the topic.

Now I need to do continuous reading of each of the files in that folder, since they are continually being updated.

I have to change any property of properties file?

My filePulseTxtFile.properties:

```
name=connect-file-pulse-txt
connector.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector
topic=lineas-fichero
tasks.max=1

 File types
fs.scan.filters=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.scanner.local.filter.RegexFileListFilter
file.filter.regex.pattern=.*\\.log$
task.reader.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.RowFileInputReader

 File scanning
fs.cleanup.policy.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.clean.LogCleanupPolicy
fs.scanner.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.scanner.local.LocalFSDirectoryWalker

fs.scan.directory.path=/home/ec2-user/parser/scanDirKafka
fs.scan.interval.ms=10000

 Internal Reporting
internal.kafka.reporter.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
internal.kafka.reporter.id=connect-file-pulse-txt
internal.kafka.reporter.topic=connect-file-pulse-status

 Track file by name
offset.strategy=name
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd suggest using something like Filebeat or Fluentd if you want to actually `tail` log files, otherwise, use a rotating log writer, then move the files to a new name (per hour/day) where they do get picked up

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation says that there is the option of continuous reading. Another thing is knowing how to do it.

Comment: You might get a more direct answer with a [Github issue](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse/issues)

Comment: Thaks, meanwhile I'm looking at the Filebit documentation

Answer (score 1):

Continious reading is only supported by the [`RowFileInputReader`](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/file-readers/#rowfileinputreader-default) that you can configure with the `read.max.wait.ms` property - **The maximum time to wait in milliseconds for more bytes after hitting end of file.**

For example, if you configure that property to `10000` then the reader will wait 10 seconds for new lines to be added to the file before considering it completed.

Also, you should note that as long as there are task processing files, then new files that are added to the source directory will not be selected. But, you can configure the `allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms` to force all tasks to be restarted after a given period so that new files will be scheduled.

Finally, you must take care to correctly set the `max.tasks` property so that all files can be processed in parallel (a task can only process one file at a time).

Comment: is "allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms" and "fs.scan.interval.ms" is necessary to be the same? because once it will scan then only, it should reconfigure itself.

Comment: The `fs.scan.internal.ms` (or `fs.listing.interval.ms` since 2.0) is the time interval between two successive scan of the file system. If new files are detected but some previous files are still being processing, then the connector will wait up to `allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms` before allowing the tasks to be reconfigured. So for example, if  `fs.scan.internal.ms` is configured to 1 hour and `allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms=0` then the connector will look up for new files after 1 hour and schedule them immediately regardless previous files are completed or not.

Comment: okay; thanks for this clarification, fhussonnois. In my case, I can see some of the files are getting processed more than once. I have actually kept the logger into the LogCleanupPolicy class. I can see for one file, The logs came around 40 times. Do you think, it can be the issue of "new files after 1 hour and schedule them immediately regardless previous files are completed or not". I am scanning 4K times with fs.scan.internal.ms as 5 mins and allow.tasks.reconfiguration.after.timeout.ms=1 min