# FilePulse SourceConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to continuously reading csv file in ksqldb with FilePulse Source Connector but it not work correctly

a) the connector read the file only once or
b) the connector read all data from file, but in that case there are duplicities in kafka topic (every time when connector read the appended file then insert all data from file into topic - not only the changed data

Is there any options how to solve this? (to continuously read only appended data from file or remove duplicities in kafka topic)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the file source connector doesn't track the file content. The connector only sees a modified file, so reads the whole thing on any update. Otherwise, reading the file once is expected behavior and you should reset your consumer offsets to handle this in your processing logic; for example make a table in ksql

If you want to tail a file for appends, other options like the spooldir connector, or Filebeat/Fluentd would be preferred (and are actually documented as being production-grade solutions for reading files into Kafka)

Comment: Thank you, I will try Filebeat/Fluentd as you mentioned. But how the Filebeat know what was appended as new into the file?

Comment: I assume it tracks byte/line offsets within the file, but I don't really know

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Connect FilePulse*

Connect FilePulse is probably not the best solution for continuously reading files. And as already mentioned in other answers: it might be a good idea to use solutions like: [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/fr/beats/filebeat), [Fluentd](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd) or [Logstash](https://github.com/elastic/logstash).

But, FilePulse actually supports continous reading using the [LocalRowFileInputReader](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/file-readers/#rowfileinputreader-default) with the reader's property `read.max.wait.ms`. Here is an older answer for a question similar to yours: [Stackoverflow: How can be configured kafka-connect-file-pulse for continuous reading of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889121/how-can-be-configured-kafka-connect-file-pulse-for-continuous-reading-of-a-text)